# why ?? is not working with ternary operator

Tags: typescript

why Null Coalescing is not working with ternary operator. I would expect to get tdy.

```
const test = {
  todo: {
    day: 'tdy'
  }
}

const filterDayRange = [{
    day: 'mon'
}]

 const result =
      test.todo?.day ?? filterDayRange.length > 0 ? filterDayRange[0].day : 'tdy';

console.log(result)


// expected Output: tdy
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCm0YF4YG8BQM4gCYgC50tsZcBDATyIHIpdKaSBfDVjUSWAMwEsAbBACcAIlQBK5MAHN4KGAG1MpMlVoBbcE2YBdDFk5IhiAK6CUJFQmgA6KHhAB%20GxUoxHjmH0HxREqbI2-PAyUAAWMAB8MAAM7l4CwmKUkjLwCjE6LlQwtPSMANwc4BAgwUEg0gAUxhBmUACUQA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply add Parantheses :

```
 test.todo?.day ?? (filterDayRange.length > 0 ? filterDayRange[0].day : 'tdy');
```

and now it works fine

Answer (score 2):

separate the ternary operator will fix the issue

```
let result = test.todo?.day ?? (filterDayRange.length > 0 ? filterDayRange[0].day : 'tdy')
```

Answer (score 0):

Everythings seems to work as expected.
filterDayRange.length > 0 evaluates to truth.
You can test it by replacing the result expressions in ternary operator

```
const test  = {
  todo: { 
    day: 'tdy'
  }
}

const filterDayRange = [{
    day: 'mon'
}]

 const result =
      test.todo?.day ?? filterDayRange.length > 0 ? 'tdy': filterDayRange[0].day;

console.log(result)
```